# EDIT: How to restore instance from scheduled snapshots in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance, snapshot

I have a scheduled daily snapshot in GCP for one of my instances. I have several snapshots now. The first one is the full snapshot and the rest of the snapshots only contain changed data.

I want to be able to restore and boot the instance but it fails to boot. Checking the serial console I see reference to a blue screen and then it reboots and shows the same errors again, repeating the reboot cycle.
I have followed the guide in GCP on how to restore an instance from a snapshot by creating a new instance, selecting the snapshot tab and then selecting my snapshot. After saving the instance and trying to boot it I get the blue screen message.

Also, if I create a new instance and use a Windows 2008 R2 Datacenter image the system obviously boots fine but if I try to attach the snapshot disk as a secondary disk (non-boot) then I get the error: Editing VM instance failed. Error: Supplied fingerprint does not match current metadata fingerprint. I'm not sure if this is related to my issue with unable to boot the OS from my snapshot.

I did find a workaround:

1) create an image of running instance (my instance is Win'2008 R2 Datacenter)
2) enable scheduled snapshots of this new instance (with VSS)
3) wait for a scheduled snapshot to get created (hourly so must wait 1 hr)
4) create new instance from the scheduled snapshot

After all this work the instance boots just fine with all my data. Obviously not a very good workaround as now I have two instances with the same data. So I have to schedule the production system for maintenance so that I can bring it down and use the new instance so that future scheduled snapshots work if I try to restore it again. A major paint in the butt.

Anyone have any ideas as to why none of my instances boot from scheduled snapshots without my workaround? Manual snapshots work fine. And new instances also work fine with the same snapshot schedule.

Comment: Are you expressing your "theory" about snapshots OR are you reporting an incorrect behavior (bug)? You can use any snapshot to restore an instance. The instance will have all data at the point in time the selected snapshot was taken.

Comment: Ok but as I said the other automatic snapshots are with changes only. So some snapshots might be only 100K if there were almost no changes so I doubt you can restore an instance from these snapshots. And I just tried deleting all snapshots, waiting until the 1st scheduled snapshot is created and that instance still won't boot using the 1st scheduled snapshot. I can only restore instances if I manually create my own snapshot. See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots

Comment: If I look at the serial console then I see it's bluescreening likely because it doesn't have all the data:
                                                                                                                   
SAC><?xml><BP>                                                                                                     
<INSTANCE CLASSNAME="BLUESCREEN">                                                                                  
<PROPERTY NAME="STOPCODE" TYPE="string"><VALUE>"0x7B"</VALUE></PROPERTY>

Comment: Your theory is wrong. You can create an instance from any bootable snapshot. All Google snapshots in a chain can be used (incremental or full). Please edit your question with a reproducible problem including the steps to create and the exact error messages. You mention "Blue Screen" so include the image name that you are creating the instance from.

Comment: My 1st process: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/scheduled-snapshots

Comment: 2nd process: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance#createsnapshot. I'm using the gCloud console. Instance is Windows-server-2008-r2-dc-v20190827. I'm just selecting the scheduled snapshot under Source Type. Instance never boots up successfully. And I'm not creating an instance from an image but from snapshot. I only listed the original image of the working instance.

Comment: The only error I see is after enabling Serial Port in instance and selecting Connect to Serial console which shows (I can't fit it all) what I pasted above starting with SAC, ClassName=BlueScreen, Value=0x7B...

Comment: Edit your question with additional information. Do not post links, your question must be complete by itself.

Comment: I can't fit all the additional information you're asking. So in short I'm: 1) Creating a scheduled snapshot of a Win'2008R2 DataCenter image. Then I'm creating a new instance using the snapshot that was auto created. This creates a disk which I attach to the new instance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198894/discussion-between-yorkman-and-john-hanley).

Comment: I am trying to help you before someone closes your question. We do not need to chat about this. Read the link and my comments and create a good question that can be answered/solved. I cannot help you further. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm asking is, "When creating a new instance using a snapshot, why doesn't the instance boot successfully?"

Comment: I just created an instance this morning migrating a Debian server. I did not have a problem. You are asking why your effort does not work without details which means we do not know. Read the link I sent you and rewrite your question.

Comment: Sorry I'm not trying to argue but your link doesn't say what details you're looking for. I've included the process, steps and details I could think of on how I'm trying to restore an instance from a snapshot. And you're saying you are able to migrate a debian server which is not what I'm trying to do. Try creating a snapshot schedule first, attaching it to your instance and then creating a new instance using one of these snapshots and see if your Windows 2008 R2 DataCenter boots. I'd be happy to include more details if you specify exactly what you want. I gave you my image, process and error.

Comment: I've updated my original question with more details. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem. I tried multiple scheduled snapshots with the same result UNTIL I made a change in the VM Instance when attaching the restored snapshot. Maybe it's just Windows but if you named the disk something different then it seems to fail.

My original disk was called `disk-1` for example. When I restored the snapshot I did it to `disk-1-a` and attached it to my instance. It failed the same way yours did. When I attach it and under "Device name" for the boot disk, select Custom and entered my original disk name of `disk-1`, it booted and RDP worked.

Comment: Thank you MIchael. It's been a long time since I've run into this problem again. Glad I asked before and that you responded with a working solution. I renamed the device name to match the original instance disk name and now it boots up. Thanks again for your answer.